# Swapping images with click functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, click

I'm working on a mobile app using JQuery and HTML. I want to be able to swap images with a click function. This is what I've had success with so far

HTML:

```
<table align="center" width="50%">
   <tr>
       <td align="center" id="one"><img src="image1.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />
            <img src="" id="" width="90" height="90" />
       </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Code:

```
$("#swap").click(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="image2.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />')
        $("#swap").click(function(){
        {
            $(this.).replaceWith('<img src="image1.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />')
        }
}
```

The only issue with this set up is that it only swaps the images as many times as it's nested. I want to be able to swap them indefinitely. I've tried CSS methods I found on this site with success with the swapping but the images were off the the side and had a white background. I also tried making checkboxes with images with some success but with other issues arising on the way. This is the only semi successful way I have found to do this with what I have found and my current knowledge.

Any help is appreciated.

Mike

Comment: I don't understand why the nesting?  Please explain...

Comment: Not able to understand this *The only issue with this set up is that it only swaps the images as many times as it's nested. I want to be able to swap them indefinitely*. Also, there are many syntax errors.

Comment: Also, dont' have multiple #swap elements.  Use class 'swap'.

Comment: Note since you replace the element, you lose the click handler on it, you should use delegation, ie: jQuery("#one").on("click","#swap"....` And you do not really need to replace the element, just change the images src attribute.

Comment: And what does swapping image mean exactly?

Comment: Ohhhhh the image is replaced with another one.  I thought two elements swapped positions...

Comment: @ShaunakD, you would still have click handler issues with that, as setting the html would still replace the element that had the click handler attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only 1 click handler where you can check the current src of the image and swap the source like

```
$("#swap").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', this.src.indexOf('image2.png') > -1 ? 'image1.png': 'image2.png')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4Lrf0zj6/)

Comment: I like this solution, but he may want to change alt and the other attributes too.

Comment: @braks, and OP can still do that, they would just need to use separate `.attr` calls, or just pass an object with the attributes to change

Comment: @ShaunakD `<img src="image1.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />`?

Comment: @ShaunakD, the id of the TD is `one`, it never changes

Comment: aHH, SORRY. I'm on my phone, the indentation wasn't allowing me to see the inner `<img>`. My bad. Apologies!

Comment: This works perfectly. I knew there had to be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Is there someway I could use an if statement or something else to tell which picture was active? So something like if image1 == true do something else if image 2  == true so something else?

Comment: @user3618687 where do you want to do that? inside the  click handler or somewhere else

Comment: Inside the click function

Comment: You have just saved me days of research. As you can probably tell I am fairly new to coding in general. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Okay Mike!

The problem you seem to be having is that the click listener isn't looking at the SAME element. When you swapped it, you basically removed the element and replaced it with a new one, so the listener can't even find the element. To fix this, try using a $("#swap").one('click', function) and nesting that inside the function itself.

Something like this:

```
function fn(e) {
    ...
    $(selector).one('click', fn);
}

$(selector).one('click', fn);
```

Comment: Was halfway through writing exactly the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

try this 
in html

```
<table align="center" width="50%">
   <tr>
       <td align="center" id="one"><img src="image1.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />
       </td>
   <tr>
</table>
```

in js

```
$("#swap").click(function(){
    var imgsrc =  $(this).attr('src');
    if(imgsrc  == 'image2.png'){
       $(this).attr('src', 'image1.png' );
    }else{
       $(this).attr('src', 'image2.png' );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I would prefer to work with.

```
$("#one").on("click", ".swap", function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass("swap-2"))
  {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="image2.png" class="swap swap-1" width="90" height="90">');
  }
  else {
    $(this).replaceWith('<img src="image1.png" class="swap swap-2" width="90" height="90">');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table align="center" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" id="one">
                <img src="image1.png" id="swap" width="90" height="90" />
                <img src="" id="" width="90" height="90" />
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>


    var index=1;
    var images=["image1.png", "image2.png"];
    $("#swap").click(function(){
        $(this).attr("src",images[index]);
        if(index == images.length-1){
            index=0;
    }
    else{
       index++;
    }   
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ho7Lxkbf/1/